# Javascript interfering CakePHP data save

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I have styled the radios with bootstrap to make them look like buttons. 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

It looks like this. This is not the problem yet:

```
<div data-toggle="buttons">
    <label>Gender</label><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Student][0][gender]" id="PostGender_" value=""/>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="data[Student][0][gender]" id="PostGender0" value="0" autocomplete="off"/> Male
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">             
        <input type="radio" name="data[Student][0][gender]" id="PostGender1" value="1" autocomplete="off"/> Female
    </label>
</div>
```

Then I add another bootstrap js to it, making the radio text change on selection. Basically an id field and 'data-complete-text' attribute is added to the labels:

```
<div data-toggle="buttons">
    <label>Gender</label><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Student][0][gender]" id="PostGender_" value=""/>
    <label class="btn btn-default" id="male" data-complete-text="Male <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true'></span>">
        <input type="radio" name="data[Student][0][gender]" id="PostGender0" value="0" autocomplete="off"/> Male
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" id="Female" data-complete-text="Female <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true'></span>">             
        <input type="radio" name="data[Student][0][gender]" id="PostGender1" value="1" autocomplete="off"/> Female
    </label>
</div>
```

And of course the script:

```
<script>
  $('#male, #female').click(function () {
    $(this).button('complete') 
  });
   $('#male').click(function () {
    $('#female').button('reset') 
  });
   $('#female').click(function () {
    $('#male').button('reset')
  }); 
</script>
```

After adding the text changing feature `$this->request->data` array receives empty value on `[gender]` key: `[gender] =>`

I am very confused...

Comment: Have you checked same for value "1" as selected. Because "0" means empty too.

Comment: Ya tried strings too, 'male', 'female'..